# Android WebView send base64 url to Javascript (Refusing to load URL as it exceeds X characters.)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, base64

I'm trying to send a base64 image to javascript but I keep getting this error in Android Studio:

W/chromium: [WARNING:navigator_impl.cc(280)] Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters.

I've tried using loadDataWithBaseURL but I can't figure out how to make it actually run any Javascript so I'm not sure if that's a solution.

This is the code I'm using, it works for some images but some are too large and it gives me that error :(

Thanks for any help!

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setFileUri('" + selectedImage.toString() + "')");
    String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
    //myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setFilePath('" + path + "')");


    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setFilePath('" + encodedImage + "')");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you found an answer to this yet or not, but I was struggling with the same thing all day trying to send an image to Javascript.  As with you, loadUrl was giving me the '2097152' error, so I tried using evaluateJavascript but kept getting webview syntax errors.  After playing around with it, I finally got it to work like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

try {
    final String retFunction = "imageReturnFunction('data:image/png;base64," + URLEncoder.encode(encoded, "UTF-8") + "');";

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            webView.evaluateJavascript(retFunction, null);
        }
    });
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that I needed it to be formatted as a dataURL in my case (which would be pretty common in a JS app), but you can adjust the code if needed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm not in a position right now to try this but if anyone says it works/helps I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: you are my saviour <3 `URLEncoder.encode` saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on bastecklein answer

```
val jsFunction = "$jsEntryPoint('data:image/jpeg;base64," +
                    base64String.replace("\n", "") 
                    +"');"`
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer was very late. But suddenly someone will come in handy.
When I had a problem, I decided to reduce the size of the string to be passed to the WebView.
Perhaps my solution will suit you:

```
 public static String prepareImageForWebView(String img64) {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 0x100000; // 1048576
    if (img64.length() > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(img64, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, o);

        int scale = 1;
        while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale++;
        }

        if (scale > 1) {
            scale--;

            // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
            // larger than target
            o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, o);

            // resize to desired dimensions
            assert bitmap != null;
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();

            double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (((double) width) / height));
            double x = (y / height) * width;

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) x, (int) y, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = scaledBitmap;

            System.gc();
        }

        if (bitmap == null) {
            return img64;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
        bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } else {
        return img64;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
 image = "<img style=\"display:inline;height:auto; max-width:100%;\" " +
                "src=\"data:image/jpg; base64," +
                prepareImageForWebView(imageData) + "\" />";
webView.loadData(image, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

By changing IMAGE_MAX_SIZE, you can choose the size of the Base64 string that suits you at the output. For example, base64 with a size of 6 MB after recompression has sufficient quality for confident reading of the text in the A4 image